# Why can't I install npm packages on Ubuntu 18.04.1?

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install mysql, nodejs, and express and mysql modules for node on Ubuntu 18.04.01, this is what I am doing step by step:

1. install ubuntu
2. sudo apt-add-repository universe && sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
3. sudo apt -y install fail2ban mysql-server build-essential
4. sudo ufw allow OpenSSH && sudo ufw enable
5. sudo mysql_secure_installation
6. alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; flush privileges;
7. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
8. mkdir nodedbtest && cd nodedbtest
9. touch index.js
10. npm init
11. npm install express

and upon doing #11, i get this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
npm ERR! The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/willdorf/.npm/_logs/2018-11-05T00_14_18_703Z-debug.log
```

this is the log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', 'mysql' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose npm-session 2456a42eb4ea509e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for mysql@latest The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
8 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 14ms
9 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3340ms
10 verbose stack TypeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
10 verbose stack     at lookup (dns.js:113:11)
10 verbose stack     at net.js:1006:5
10 verbose stack     at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
10 verbose stack     at lookupAndConnect (net.js:1005:3)
10 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.Socket.connect (net.js:940:5)
10 verbose stack     at Object.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1148:12)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createConnection (https.js:119:22)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:265:26)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.createSocket (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:77:11)
10 verbose stack     at HttpsAgent.addRequest (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/_http_agent.js:239:10)
10 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:248:16)
10 verbose stack     at request (https.js:280:10)
10 verbose stack     at fetch.Promise (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:54:17)
10 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
10 verbose stack     at fetch (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:41:10)
10 verbose stack     at retry (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/index.js:332:14)
11 verbose cwd /home/willdorf/nodedbtest
12 verbose Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
13 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mysql"
14 verbose node v10.13.0
15 verbose npm  v6.4.1
16 error code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
17 error The value "4294967295" is invalid for option "family"
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Could you try to install an older version of node? Like 8.x

Comment: per this - this is a problem with version of node on Ubuntu . - https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19348 - move to older version of node and see if it works. -

Comment: I've tried 8.12 a few days ago (was latest Node LTS version) and now 10.13 (is now latest LTS version) same results... have another server running Ubuntu 16.04.5 with Node 8.12 and works fine... think maybe this is an Ubuntu 18.04.1 issue

Answer (score 0):

Try the following worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-add-repository universe && sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt -y install fail2ban mysql-server build-essential
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH && sudo ufw enable
sudo mysql_secure_installation
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - && sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
mkdir nodedbtest && cd nodedbtest
touch index.js
npm init
npm install express
```